# Expected time for winning in biased Gambler's Ruin

Tags: probability, markov-chains, random-walk

Consider the random walk $X_0, X_1, X_2, \ldots$ on state space $S=\{0,1,\ldots,n\}$ with absorbing states $A=\{0,n\}$, and with $P(i,i+1)=p$ and $P(i,i-1)=q$ for all $i \in S \setminus A$, where $p+q=1$ and $p,q>0$.

Let $T$ denote the number of steps until the walk is absorbed in either $0$ or $n$.

Let $\mathbb{E}_k(\cdot) := \mathbb\{\cdot | X_0 = k\}$ denote the expectation conditioned on starting in state $k \in S \setminus A$.

How to compute $\mathbb{E}_k(T|X_T = n)$?

Comment: Which steps of the usual approach to compute $E_k(T:X_T=n)$ and $P_k(X_T=n)$ elude you?

Comment: What is the 'usual approach'? Indeed I can determine $P_k(X_T=n)$ and $\mathbb{E}_k(T)$ by solving recurrence relations. But I cannot retrieve $\mathbb{E}_k(T|X_t=n)$ from that, and the recurrence for it seems far too complicated to me, even in the case $p=q=1/2$. Are there other approaches?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The usual approach:

For every $0\leqslant k\leqslant n$, let $u_k=E_k(T:X_T=n)$ and $v_k=P_k(X_T=n)$, then $(u_k)$ and $(v_k)$ are determined by the fact that $u_0=u_n=v_0=0$, $v_n=1$, and, for every $1\leqslant k\leqslant n-1$, 
$$
u_k=v_k+pu_{k+1}+qu_{k-1},\qquad
v_k=pv_{k+1}+qv_{k-1}.
$$
The $(v_k)$ system is solved using the usual characteristic equation approach. When $p\ne q$, this yields, for every $0\leqslant k\leqslant n$, 
$$
v_k=\frac{1-r^k}{1-r^n},\qquad r=\frac{q}p.
$$
Plugging this into the $(u_k)$ system and fiddling a little bit with particular solutions such as $u_k=k$, $u_k=r^k$ and $u_k=kr^k$, one can solve for $(u_k)$ and finally deduce the value of 
$$
E_k(T\mid X_T=n)=\frac{u_k}{v_k}.
$$
The case $p=q=\frac12$ is degenerate since $r=1$. Then, $v_k=\frac{k}n$ and,  trying particular solutions such as $u_k=k$, $u_k=k^2$ and $u_k=k^3$, one gets $u_k=\frac13nk-\frac1{3n}k^3$, hence
$$
E_k(T\mid X_T=n)=\tfrac13(n^2-k^2).
$$

Comment: What is the reasoning for $u_k = v_k + pu_{k+1} + qu_{k-1}$? With $L$ the length of a random path $\alpha$, I get instead that: $u_k=E_k(T|X_T=n)=\sum_{l=0}^\infty l P_k(L=l|X_T=n)=v_k^{-1} \sum_{l=1}^\infty l P_k(L=l \wedge X_T=n) = v_k^{-1} \sum_{l=1}^\infty l (\sum_{\alpha=k,k-1,...,n, |\alpha|=l}P(\alpha) + \sum_{\alpha=k,k+1,...,n, |\alpha|=l}P(\alpha)) = ... = v_k^{-1} (q ( v_{k-1} u_{k-1} + v_{k-1}) + p ( v_{k+1} u_{k+1} + v_{k+1}) = q \frac{v_{k-1}}{v_k} u_{k-1} + p \frac{v_{k+1}}{v_k} u_{k+1} + \frac{q v_{k-1} + p v_{k+1}}{v_k}$.

Comment: ...which slightly simplifies to $u_k = q\frac{v_{k-1}}{v_k} u_{k-1} + p\frac{v_{k+1}}{v_k} u_{k+1} + 1$ by applying that $v_k = p v_{k+1} + q v_{k-1}$. But it still has non-constant coefficients.

Comment: @cubiclettuce Note that $u_k=E_k(T\mathbf 1_A)$ with $A=[X_T=n]$, not $E_k(T\mid A)$, hence $u_k$ in my post is $u_kv_k$ in your comment. To wit, the last identity in your post can be rewritten as $(u_kv_k)=v_k+p(v_{k+1}u_{k+1})+q(v_{k-1}u_{k-1})$, that is, the version in the post, once the notational mistake you made is taken care of.

Comment: Indeed the notation $E_k(\cdot : X_t = n)$ was new to me. With your last comment things clear up, since $E_k(\cdot | X_t = n) = E_K(\cdot : X_T = n) / P_k(X_T = n)$. So the trick is to consider $E_k(\cdot : X_t = n)$ instead of $E_k(\cdot | X_t = n)$ when constructing the recurrence. Thank you very, very much!

Comment: can anyone explain how to obtain to solution $u_k=\frac13nk-\frac1{3n}k^3$ by "trying" those particular solutions ?

Comment: @kchpchan Yes. $ $

Comment: I did "fiddle a little bit" for an explicit formula for $u_k$, and posted a new answer as an appendix to this answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is an appendix to the excellent answer of Did, giving an explicit formula for $u_k$ (whose derivation involves quite a lot of work).

$u_k$, that is $E_k(T:X_T=n)$, can be expressed as:$$
\frac{
    n \cdot (1 - r^k) \cdot (1 + r^n)
  - k \cdot (1 + r^k) \cdot (1 - r^n)
}{p \cdot (1 - r) \cdot (1 - r^n)^2}
$$

Analogously, $E_k(T:X_T=0)$ can be expressed as:$$
r^k \cdot \frac{
    n \cdot (1 - r^{n - k}) \cdot (1 + r^n)
  - (n - k) \cdot (1 + r^{n - k}) \cdot (1 - r^n)
}{p  \cdot (1 - r) \cdot (1 - r^n)^2}
$$

Summing both yields:$$
\frac{n \cdot (1 - r^k) - k \cdot (1 - r^n)}{p \cdot (1 - r) \cdot (1 - r^n)}
$$
which is the well-known expression for $E_k(T)$, as expected.

Comment: There is at least something wrong with your expression for $E_k(T:X_T=0)$. For a counterexample, substitute in $p=\frac{3}{4}$ (meaning $r=\frac{1}{3}$), $n=2$, and $k=1$. Your expression gives $-\frac{7}{4}$, but obviously the result must be $\geq 0$. It would be great if you could also show how you derived these expressions.

Comment: @user1145925 Could you please double-check ? I believe that the correct answer is 3 / 4 (not -7 / 4).

Comment: @user1145925 As to the derivation, Did's answer mentions the
"usual characteristic equation approach" for solving recurrence relations.
I do not remember exactly how I did it, but it was not too difficult to find
suitable explanations on the internet; perhaps
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation
is already good enough.

Comment: I had a typo before; your expression is in fact feasible (and probably correct). Actually, your expression yields $\frac{1}{4}$ (as shown in this WolframAlpha link: https://bit.ly/3QIWgSA).

Comment: @user1145925 Thank you verifying! Indeed, you are right, the correct answer is 1 / 4 (I evaluated both formula and took the result of the wrong one, that is, 3 / 4, but otherwise our results agree now). I am reasonably sure that my derivations were correct, because I derived both formulae separately, and checked them by adding them, finding the expected well-known result. But I did not write simulations to compare experimental and theoretical values.

Comment: @user1145925 I just have run some simulations, and the observed averages are acceptably close to the theoretical values. Thus, my confidence in my own derivations is now very high.

Answer (score 0):

The answer given only provides an explicit solution for the case p=q=.5

Here is a general solution to the above problem.  You can plug in the gamblers starting amount,  the final amount, the bias of the coin and get a numerical answer for  exactly how many tosses on average it takes for the gambler to win the game.

(I will submit the derivation of my solution when i get my latex skills working again.)

Statement of the Problem in plain english,
A coin is biased to come up heads with probability p , where p is between 0 and 1.
If a gambler starts with m  and bets heads each toss.  The game ends when the
gambler has gone broke (lost m) ,  or has attained n ( won  [n-m] )

PROBLEM- Given, p, m, n   - what is Tw(m,n,p).
        compute the  average length of a WON game.

first,  note that we only need to solve for the gambler starting out with 1,  (m=1) since the time to win  n starting with 1  is equal to the time to win m starting with 1 plus the time to win (n-m) starting with m.   i.e. Tw(m,n,p)= Tw(1,n,p)-Tw(1,m,p)

---

So we'll only set out to solve for the case m=1,  which by simple subtraction will give us the general case for any  m  from 1 to n-1.

For a biased coin,  Call the probability of winnng the coin toss = p,
and the probability of losing the toss is (1-p) = q,  and call z = q/p.

A gambler starts with 1, and tosses for stake =1  until he has 0 (ruin) or has n (Wins).

The probability of the gambler winning,  Pwin(n) is  known to be
                 Pwin(n) =  (1-z)/(1-z^n).
    The average time Twinlose(n) of a game (win OR lose) is a  known function of z and n.
   Twinlose(n)=  [n*Pwin(n)-1]/(p-q)

Twin(n) defined as the average time it takes the gambler to WIN such a game. I calculated Twin(n) and found it to be

```
 Twin(n) = Pwin(n) * (the sum over m from 0 to n of X(n,m) * z^m )
```

where X(n,m) is the given by the m-th entry of the  n-th row of this sequence.

```
     X(n,m) = n + 2*m*(n - m) (0 <= m <= n).
```

The first few rows of this sequence are-

n=1   - 1, 1   -

n=2   - 2,  4,  2  -

n=3  -  3,  7,  7,  3  -

n=4   - 4,  10, 12, 10, 4  -

n=5   -  5,  13, 17, 17, 13, 5  -

n=6   -  6,  16, 22, 24, 22, 16, 6 -

...